# SQL Server 2012 Express Edition Database Size

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

We have a requirement in our project to store millions of records(~100 million) in database.
And we know that SQL Express Edition 2012 can maximum accommodate 10GB of data.
I am using this query to get the actual size of the database - Is this right?

```
use [Bio Lambda8R32S50X]

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName,
Name AS Logical_Name,
Physical_Name, (size*8)/1024 SizeMB
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = 'Bio Lambda8R32S50X'

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON 

DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) 

-- Table row counts and sizes.
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
    [name] NVARCHAR(128),
    [rows] CHAR(11),
    reserved VARCHAR(18), 
    data VARCHAR(18), 
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
) 

INSERT #t EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 

SELECT *
FROM   #t

-- # of rows.
SELECT SUM(CAST([rows] AS int)) AS [rows]
FROM   #t

DROP TABLE #t
```

The second question is this restriction is only on the database size of the Primary file group or inclusive of the log files as well?
If we do a lot of delete and insert, or may be delete and insert back the same number of records, does the database size vary or remains the same?

This is very crucial, since this will decide whether we can go ahead with SQL Server 2012 Express Edition or not?

Thanks and regards

Subasish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the first query is to get the overall size of the database for the data and logs.  The second one is for each table.  So I would say yes to both.

Based upon my experience seeing db's over 40GB and this link[maximum DB size limits](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc107d5f-f5f7-4630-b2e2-3b149d73abd9/maximum-db-size-limits) that the limit on sql server express is based upon the mdf and ndf files not the ldf.

You might be safer however, just to go with SQL Server Standard and use CAL licensing in case your database starts growing.

Good Luck!